# upload and access files from one server to another in php

Tags: php, server

I have 2 servers called server A and server B. Now I want to host my site on server A and when some one upload any data images,videos etc i want upload these data on server B is it possible ?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: probably belongs on serverfault. here's one such question: http://serverfault.com/questions/382272/how-to-move-files-from-one-server-to-another-server-automatically

Answer (score 1):

Server A could connect to server B via. SSH and send the file that way or you could use cURL to send your files to the other server.